# How to log out of su and another user

Tags: ssh, login, su

So when I am logged in as a standard user in an ssh session and then su to root, how can I log out of both accounts with a single command?

Rather than:

```
root@host:/exit
user@host:/exit
```

something like:

```
root@host:/magicallyLogEveryoneOut -bladow
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/3246/how-can-i-force-other-users-to-log-out

Comment: Rather not a duplicate - killing the parent session does accomplish nothing.

Comment: The fastest thing would be to press ctrl-d mutiple times until the window closes...

Comment: The `CTRL-D` method is the one I would recommend.

Comment: Didn't know about ctrl-d. So smooth. #firstworldproblems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that any command you type takes more keystrokes I recommend <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, which takes you out of both sessions.

Answer (score 0):

For your exact question about doing this in one command: on one of my RHEL boxes this command works:

```
fuser -k `tty`
```

Which SIGKILL's (aka `-9`) any PID attached to the terminal. Your system's `getty` program should respawn on its own. I just tried it and it kicked me out of a session where I had `sudo`'d to root.

I'd be hesitant to do this though, since I run a lot of background jobs and I'd be paranoid that I'd leave one of them running. Also, this is pretty lazy (no offense).

I'd suggest you just have a habit of doing a `CTRL-C` followed by a bunch of `CTRL-D`' until the window closes.